# How to check if a column has a set of values in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, relational-division

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | customer_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          2 |           1 |
|          4 |           1 |
|          1 |           1 |
|          6 |           1 |
|          2 |           2 |
|          5 |           3 |
|          8 |           4 |
|          1 |           4 |
|          7 |           4 |
|          9 |           4 |
|          5 |           4 |
|         10 |           5 |
|          1 |           6 |
|          2 |           6 |
|          3 |           6 |
|          4 |           6 |
|          5 |           6 |
|          6 |           6 |
|          7 |           6 |
|          8 |           6 |
|          9 |           6 |
|         10 |           6 |
|          1 |           8 |
+------------+-------------+
```

I have table as shown above. I want to know if a customer a particular customer_id has set of product_ids (say 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).
How do I achieve this? Let us say the table name is CustProds.
For simplicity assume this is the only table in db and they have constraint fo not null.
The expected output is

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | customer_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |           6 |
|          2 |           6 |
|          3 |           6 |
|          4 |           6 |
|          5 |           6 |
|          6 |           6 |
|          7 |           6 |
|          8 |           6 |
|          9 |           6 |
|         10 |           6 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: and the constraints of the table are ...?

Comment: Show us your expected result and tag your database ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `SELECT product_id FROM product_ids WHERE customer_id = 4`

Comment: I want to know if a customer has all the products_ids (1-10)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your DBMS, it's hard to answer exactly. For an example in Oracle SQL, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT c.product_id,
       m.customer_id
FROM (
    SELECT t.customer_id,
           COUNT(*)
    FROM CustProds t
    WHERE t.product_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) /* List of items to find */
    GROUP BY t.customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.product_id) = 8 /* Number of items in list */
) m
JOIN CustProds c
     ON c.customer_id = m.customer_id
ORDER BY m.customer_id, c.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results on one row per customer as:

```
SELECT cp.customer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cp.product_id) as product_ids
FROM CustProds cp
GROUP BY cp.customer_id
HAVING SUM(cp.product_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)) = 8;
```

This assumes that the table does not have duplicates, although it can easily be tweaked to handle that situation as well.